# Is there a general summation formula for the polygamma function at $z=1/2$? i.e $\psi^{(s)}(\frac{1}{2})$ for all s.

Tags: polygamma

For $s>0$ one has $ \psi^{(s)}(\frac{1}{2}) =  s! \cdot \zeta(s+1, \frac{1}{2}) \cdot (-1)^{s+1} $.

E.g. 
$ \psi^{(1)}(\frac{1}{2}) = 3 \cdot \zeta(2) $ 
$ \psi^{(2)}(\frac{1}{2}) = -14 \cdot \zeta(3) $ 
$ \psi^{(3)}(\frac{1}{2}) = 90 \cdot \zeta(4) $ 
etc.

However, Mathematica gives 
$ \psi^{(-1)}(\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{\ln(\pi)}{2} $ 
$ \psi^{(-2)}(\frac{1}{2}) = \ln(A^\frac{3}{2}2^\frac{5}{24}\pi^\frac{1}{4}), $ where $A$ is the Glaisher-Kinkelin Constant 
$ \psi^{(-3)}(\frac{1}{2}) = \ln(A^\frac{1}{2}2^\frac{1}{16}\pi^\frac{1}{16}) + \frac{7 \zeta(3)}{32\pi^2} $

and I'm not sure how these are obtained since negative integers plugged into the formula above yields wonky results.

Comment: Aren't you missing something in your first line? Like a $\psi^{(s)}(1/2)$ or something? It is better to use $\psi ^{(s)} (1/2) = ( - 1)^{s + 1} s!\zeta (s + 1,1/2)$.

Comment: @Gary. Thanks; I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

First off we have for reference [this](http://functions.wolfram.com/06.15.03.0021.01) formula which states for all $n\in\Bbb N$
$$
\psi ^{(n)}\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right)=(-1)^{n+1} \left(2^{n+1}-1\right) n! \zeta (n+1).
$$
Note that this is not the same formula as given in your question statement. As for negative values, I was not able to find a closed-form for all $-n\in\Bbb N$ at $z=1/2$ but there is one for $-2n$ with $n\in\Bbb N$ and $z=1/2$ given [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/06.15.03.0062.01).
Furthermore, we do have a formula for general $-n$ and $z$ given [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/06.15.03.0041.01) which can be evaluated at $z=1/2$. With a little extra work you could further simplify this to the special cases you obtained using Mathematica using the well-known properties of the polygamma function.